# How can i bring share option in my angular(6+) PWA app to share media to social apps(Messenger,Whatsapp)?

Tags: angular, share, progressive-web-apps

I am working on a Progressive web app which works on both web version and mobile version. I am looking for a share option to share my generated PDF to Whatsapp(Or any other social like facebook,Messenger,LinkedIn).
Any Help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Web [Share API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/09/navigator-share)

`if ('share' in navigator) {
      navigator.share({
        title: document.title,
        text: text,
        url: location.href,
      })
    } else {
      // Here we use the WhatsApp API as fallback; remember to encode your text for URI
      location.href = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=' + encodeURIComponent(text + ' - ') + location.href
    }`